# I am trying to use the fill command, but it is not working

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am using this command and it is not working.

`/fill 79 134 41 108 129 74 <dirt> <3> replace <coarse_dirt> <3:1>`

It keeps saying that there is no such block as dirt. Why is this happening?

This is the output.

[09:36:49] There is no such block with name minecraft:

I am using minecraft 1.12.2

Comment: Please edit your question to include the full command, along with the exact output you get.

Comment: Which version of mine raft are you using? What exact error message are you getting?

Answer (score 2):

The first thing which I think is confusing you is how a command's usage syntax is written, e.g:

```
fill <x1> <y1> <z1> <x2> <y2> <z2> <block> <dataValue|state> replace [replaceBlock] [dataValue|state]
```

The angled brackets `< >` should not be put in the actual command, they're just there to indicate a required argument that you should replace with something.
Same applies to square brackets `[ ]` which indicate an optional argument.
In contrast, words without any brackets around them (e.g: `fill`, `replace`) are to be typed literally, rather than replaced with your argument.

So removing the brackets we get:

```
fill 79 134 41 108 129 74 dirt 3 replace coarse_dirt 3:1
```

---

The other confusion is that the `dataValue` is not the block's numeric ID (which have been phased out), but instead the block's metadata/"damage value". So instead of `3` for normal dirt it should be `0`, and instead of `3:1` for coarse dirt it'd be just the `1`. It'd be redundant to have to specify a block's string ID then its numeric ID. Fixing that should result in a working command:

```
fill 79 134 41 108 129 74 dirt 0 replace coarse_dirt 1
```

---

Additionally, it'd be good practice to replace the numeric `dataValue`s with `state`s:

```
fill 79 134 41 108 129 74 dirt default replace dirt variant=coarse_dirt
```

Answer (score 0):

The fill command has arbitrary and random failures that sometimes result in "0 blocks filled" message. Repeating the exact same command string has worked for me.